# Issue with Woocommerce query by meta and attributes

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have 3 products having meta key `'check_key' = 1`. 2 of them have attribute `'pa_size_10_20'` with values '100' and '30'; other one have attribute `'pa_size_30_40'` with value '70'.

Please help me understand why the query below returns all 3 products? I expect only 2 products with 'pa_size_10_20' attribute.

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'   => 'product',
    'visibility'  => 'visible',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'numberposts' => -1,
    'meta_query'  => array(
        array(
            'key'     => 'check_key',
            'value'   => '1',
            'compare' => '='
        )
    ),
   'tax_query'    => array( 
        array(
            'taxonomy'=> 'pa_size_10_20',
            'field'   => 'name',
            'terms'   => 0,
            'operator' => '!='
        )
    )
);
$posts = get_posts( $args );
```

TIA

Answer (score 0):

It seems as though your `tax_query` would return all taxonomy terms that aren't named `0` an integer?

I think if you know the values for `IN` then I would use those instead.

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'   => 'product',
    'visibility'  => 'visible',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'meta_query'  => array(
        array(
            'key'     => 'check_key',
            'value'   => '1',
            'compare' => '='
        ),
    ),
    'tax_query'    => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy'=> 'pa_size_10_20',
            'field'   => 'name',
            'terms'   => array('100', '300'),
            'operator' => 'IN'
        ),
    ),
);
```

Comment: It's not about count. The point is that query for tazonomy 'pa_size_10_20' returns also post under taxonomy 'pa_size_30_40'

Comment: All that are not zero